# Reloading classes in C# - a wierd behaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

**The introduction**

I am modding a game and want to reload the mods dynamicly at runtime, so that I don't have to restart the game every time I make a change. I have created a modding API so that a mod is just a class implementing my `ICustomCommand` interface:

```
public interface ICustomCommand
{
    string GetAuthor(); //get author, for good measure
    string GetFunctionName(); //get name, to differentiate from other mods
    void Execute(CrplCore core); //actually do the work
}
```

Example:

```
public class HelloCommandExample : ICustomCommand
{
    public void Execute(CrplCore core)
    {
        DebugText.LogMessage(core, "Hello mods: " + core.GetStringFromStack());
        Debug.Log("HelloCommandExample"); 
    }

    public string GetAuthor()
    {
        return "kajacx";
    }

    public string GetFunctionName()
    {
        return "HelloTrace";
    }
}
```

How it works right now: Modders can put multiple such classes into a `.dll` library, and them players can put those mods files into a `mod` subfolder from where all the mod classes will be loaded when the game starts.

However, once loaded like this, the mods cannot be reloaded, even if I change the .dll file and re.run the import script. This is what the import sript looks like:

```
private static void DoInit()
{
    avaliableCommands = new Dictionary<string, ICustomCommand>(); //static field

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"ParticleFleet_Data\Managed\mods");

    foreach (string file in files) //list all files in the mods directory
    {
        if (!file.ToLower().EndsWith(".dll"))
        {
            continue; //skip all non-dll files
        }
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);

            string hash;
            using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                hash = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(bytes));
            }
            Debug.LogFormat("Loading file {0}, hash: {1}", file, hash);

            //load the .dll file as and assembly
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
            Type[] types = assembly.GetExportedTypes();
            foreach (Type type in types) //list all classes from the library
            {
                if (typeof(ICustomCommand).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                {
                    //add new command from the library
                    ICustomCommand command = (ICustomCommand)assembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName);
                    AddCommand(command); //this adds the command into the avaliableCommands field
                    Debug.LogFormat("Custom command {0} by {1} loaded, usage: {2}",
                        command.GetFunctionName(), command.GetAuthor(), command.GetFunctionSignature());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.LogException(ex);
        }
    }

    Debug.Log("Total mod commands loaded: " + avaliableCommands.Count);
}
```

**The problem**

Now, here we finally get to the fun part: what does/doesn't work in this import script:

- First run correctly import all classes from all files
- Any consequential run will import the exact same calsses, even if the .dll file is changed with new content (tested with the SHA1 hash log)
- Restarting the game after that will make these changes visible
- Deleting the .dll file will make the classes not load
- Deleting the classes *from* the .dll file (rebuilding the .dll with no/different classes) will not cause any change - the old classes will still be loaded as if the .dll was not changed at all.
- Renaming the changed .dll doesn't help eighter, the old classes still get loaded
- Adding new classes to the .dll doesn't work eighter, only the old classes will get loaded
- Changing the namespaces of the classes inside the .dll doesn't work
- Renaming the classes inside the .dll doesn't work
- *However*, chaning the content of the .dll *does* change the hash.

After seeing this list, I can only come to 1 conclusion: **There is some hidden ID inside the DLL and the assembly loaded uses it to cache the DLL files**. This ID is probably something like the name (with path) of the Visual Studio project in which I created the .dll library.

**The question**

So, my question: Is there a way to disable this caching, or to generate different ID every time I build the library?

I will be more than happy to change the namespace of the classes every time I save them if there will be another problem with loading the same class multiple times, but right now, the problem is that `Assembly.Load` loads the same assembly over and over again, regardless of what data I feed into it.

And yes, I have tried using an `AppDomain`, but creating one crashes because this is inside a Unity project, so unless you know how work around this problem in Unity specifically, I cannot use `AppDomain` unfortunately.

Comment: Consider adding [tag:Unity3d] as a tag

Comment: Have you tried [this approach](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/appdomain-createinstanceandunwrap-filenotfoundexception.295406/) to create new `AppDomain`? Without creating it your options are strongly limited...

Comment: Did you try to change the [assembly name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/assembly-names)?

Comment: wow, thanks for the links, I'll do check them out and report back with (hopefully possitive) results